# ¿Cuándo apareció por primera vez la expresión "¿De qué color es el caballo blanco de Santiago?"?

Tags: expresiones

La cuestión no es, ¿por qué el caballo de Santiago es blanco?, sino desde cuando existe tal expresión. ¿Cuándo fue la primera vez que aparece de forma escrita?

Retrocediendo y rememorando algunos datos generales sobre los acontecimientos;

- El Apóstol Santiago se presentó en la batalla de Clavijo montado en un caballo blanco y con la espada en mano ayudó a los cristiano a ganar a los árabes. Desde entonces parece ser que posee el sobrenombre de Santiago matamoros. Por tanto, se dice que es desde esa época, a mediados del siglo IX, es cuando ya se comienza a utilizar la expresión.
- Por otra parte Américo Castro, historiador del siglo XX, sostenía que en las batallas de los reyes hispanos contra los musulmanes vinieron en socorro, de forma prodigiosa, tanto Santiago como San Millán y que los dos montaban caballos blancos. En Santiago de Compostela, en el altar mayor del monasterio de San Martín Pinario, se puede observar que en lo alto, a la derecha y a la izquierda, hay dos santos montados en caballos blancos, uno es el Apóstol Santiago y el otro San Millán, fraile que los benedictinos consideran suyo.

Realicé la pregunta a círculos de bibliotecas y otras instituciones, que no supieron responder.
Gracias

Comment: Creo que la pregunta se basa en una premisa falsa. En Colombia he oído la expresión con Bolivar en lugar de Santiago. Una corta búsqueda en google resulta en: ¿de que color es el caballo blanco de...(San Martin, Napoleon, Bolivar, Santiago, Cristobal Colon, Miguel Grau)? En conclusión, la expresión no tiene nada que ver con Santiago.

Comment: Como ya te indicó @DGaleano, la premisa es falsa. Si lees mi respuesta, verás que va mucho más allá, pues es una leyenda absoluta, que hoy en día ningún historiador serio tendría en cuenta. Por esa razón, me parece raro que nadie te supiera responder a tu pregunta, cuando yo (que soy un simple aficionado a las palabras) he podido rastrear y encontrarla por mí mismo. Sin embargo, te di un voto afirmativo, porque me diste la oportunidad de responder a una falacia que está (todavía) muy extendida entre la población.

Answer (score 1):

La primera cita sobre el caballo blanco de Santiago data del año 1243, cuando **Rodrigo Jiménez de Rada**, arzobispo de Toledo, en su obra *De rebus Hispanae* (traducida al castellano como *Crónica de España*) escribe:

> "(...) adormecióse  el  rey  don  Ramiro  e  veno  á  él  el  Apóstol  Santiago  e díxole: — Sepa  el  rey  don  Ramiro,  que  quando  el  mi  Señor  Jesucristo partió  á  mí  e  á  mis  hermanos  los  Apóstoles  las  prouincias de  la  tierra  todas,  que  dio  á  mí  solo  toda  España  en  mi  guarda, que  la  amparase  e  la  defendiese  de  todos  los  enemigos  de  la  fé.  E desque  todo  esto  le  ovo  dicho,  allegóse  á  él,  e  tomóle  por  la  mano, e  díxole: — Esfuérzate  e  sey  bien  firme,  que  yo  so  Diago,  el  Apóstol  de  Jesucristo,  e  vengo  te  ayudar  contra  estos  tus  enemigos.  E sepas  por  verdat  que  los  vencerás  eras  mañana  con  el  ayuda  de Dios.  E  digo  que  averá  y  muchos  muertos  de  los  tuyos  para  los quales  está  aparejada  la  gloria  perdurable.  E  porque  non  dubdes nada  en  esto  que  te  digo,  verme  has  mañana  andar  ahi  en  un **cauallo  blanco**  con  una  seña  grand,  e  tú  con  todos  los  tuyos,  luego eras  por  la  mañana  confesar  vos  hedes  muy  bien  de  todos  vuestros pecados,  e  rescebiredes  el  cuerpo  e  la  sangre  de  Nuestro  Señor Jesucristo.  E  pues  que  lo  ouierdes  fecho,  non  dubdedes  de  entrar syn  miedo  por  la  hueste  de  los  moros  bárbaros  e  de  ferir  en  ellos llamando  el  nombre  de  Dios  e  el  mío,  que  sepas  por  cierto  que todos  los  meterás  á  espada  e  los  matarás."

Este texto es realmente el origen del mito del **caballo blanco de Santiago**, así como de la propia **batalla de Clavijo**, inventada por el avispado arzobispo, cuyas fabulaciones pasaron a formar parte de nuestra propia cultura.